# Why doesn't system(@array) work when @array contains a find command?

Tags: perl

I'm beginning to love Perl, but I don't understand whats going on here.

why does this work

```
my @cmd = ();
push @cmd, 'find';
push @cmd, 'data/path/';
push @cmd, "-name";
push @cmd, '*.xml';
push @cmd, '-exec';
push @cmd, 'mv';
push @cmd, '{}';
push @cmd, 'junk/path/';
push @cmd, '\;';    
say join (' ', @cmd);       
system(join(' ', @cmd));
```

Output

```
find data/path/ -name *.xml -exec mv {} junk/path/ \;
```

No errors from find! While this does not work

```
my @cmd = ();       
push @cmd, 'find';
push @cmd, 'data/path/';
push @cmd, "-name";
push @cmd, '*.xml';
push @cmd, '-exec';
push @cmd, 'mv';
push @cmd, '{}';
push @cmd, 'junk/path/';
push @cmd, '\;';    
say join (' ', @cmd);       
system(@cmd);
```

Output:

```
find data/path/ -name *.xml -exec mv {} junk/path/ \;
find: Missing argument for »-exec«.
```

`system` should be able to understand arrays. See [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html). When I copy the output into shell, there is no missing argument, it just works. But my script can't execute this.

Comment: Is it a typo that your second push (for data/path/) doesn't have a quote in the first case?

Comment: Side note: Instead of all those `push` statements, you can do `my @cmd = qw(find data/path/ -name *.xml -exec mv {} junk/path/ \;);`.

Comment: ^^ (Assuming none of your paths contain spaces.)

Comment: `\;` in the shell is equivalent to `';'`. You have to do like you did for `'*.xml'` and pass what the shell would pass for that argument rather than the shell literal itself.

Comment: Yes that was a typo. I can't use `qw` as I get my paths from a config object. I just simplified this here to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the second `system` call, you shouldn't escape the `;`.

The `-exec` switch to `find` slurps arguments until it finds a `;`. `;` is interpreted by the shell as a command separator, so when you run `find ... -exec` from the command-line, you need to escape it, and in shell scripts you'll see the pattern

```
find ... -exec ... \;
```

In your second `system` call, you collect all of the arguments in an array and pass the array directly to `system`. In this case, Perl is not using the shell to interpret the command, and the `find` command sees the argument `\;` instead of `;`, and the `-exec` switch gets confused.

All you need to say to get your `system` command to work is

```
...
push @cmd, ';';
...
system(@cmd);
```

Comment: And why can't `exec` and `mv {}` or `name`and `<filename>` stay in the same array value? Then it throws similar parser errors. I also have such problems with `cat *.xml >> summary.xml`.

Comment: Because in `system(@LIST)`, every element of `@LIST` is treated as a single command-line argument. `find` supports a switch called `-exec`, but it doesn't support a switch called `-exec mv {}`. Input/output redirection (`<file`, `>file`, `>>file`, `2>&1`, ...) are implemented in the shell, not the underlying system call. `system(@LIST)` bypasses the shell, so the I/O redirection operators are interpreted as normal command-line arguments, as if you said `cat *.xml '>>' summary.xml`.

Answer (score 5):

[mob pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42093924) the immediate problem with your `system` call, but there's a better way to do this. Instead of executing an external command, you can use [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule), which has an interface that's very similar to the `find` utility:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Copy;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $dest = '/foo/bar';

File::Find::Rule->file
                ->name('*.xml')
                ->exec( sub { move($_, $dest) or warn "move($_, $dest) failed: $!" } )
                ->in('.');
```

Comment: Thanks, but we shall avoid modules because it can be tricky to install them on `Suse`. Not my decision.

Comment: @Corni You can also use the core module [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html), although the interface isn't as nice. You really shouldn't rely on external programs to do things that are easy to do in pure Perl, since it makes your programs less portable and makes debugging and error handling more difficult.

Comment: You are right. Many of my `system`calls do not work as expected. I'll talk to our admin if we could use `File::Find::Rule.`